# Reason behind the given claim?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N$ denote a set containing numbers from $1$ to $n$.
suppose $N = 3$, then $$F(3) = (1) + (2) + (3) + (1+2) + (1+3) + (2+3) + (1+2+3) = 24$$
$$F(4) = 80$$
Thus $F(N)$  represents the sum of all the elements of all the subsets possible excluding null set.

Let $G(N) = F(1) + F(2) + ........ + F(N)$ ;

$G(1) = 1$ ;

$G(2) = F(2) + G(1) = 6 + 1 = 7$;

$G(3) = F(3) + G(2) = 24 + 7 = 31$

I need to find $G(N) \mod 8388608$ where $N \leq 10 ^{10}$.

While solving the problem I noticed that 
$$F(N) = 2 ^{N-1} \cdot\frac{N \cdot(N+1)}{2}$$
Reason : No. of occurences of each element is same while adding all the elements of all the subsets.  As in case of $N = 3$ , No. of 1's = No. of 2's = .. = No. of 4's = 4 = $2^{N-1};

But as $N$ is very large storing all the answers for all $N$'s is in efficient and time consuming. So I looked into the solution which claimed that for $N \leq 21$. G(N) can be calculated in the same manner as give above. However $G(N)  = 8388607$ for $N \gt 21$.
It can be also be calculated by the expression

```
     G(N) = (power(2,N)*(((N*N-N+2)/2)%MOD))%MOD; where MOD = 8388608 ;
```

Can anyone give a proof or explain how one can arrive on this result ?
Link for the [problem](http://www.codechef.com/problems/RESN05/) .